# Center legend not by all chart but by plot area only

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

```
legend: {
    align: 'center',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    layout: 'horizontal',
},
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/orLbwy8d/6/)

How you can see in fiddle the legend center by all area.But I need center it only by plot area

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the green line includes the length of the labels and the title on the yAxis, it will work. Add "x:25" to compensate the distance. Please check below:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mushigh/orLbwy8d/5/)

```
legend: {
        align: 'center',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        layout: 'horizontal',
        x:25
    },
```

Comment: But 25 is hardcoded value.What if yaxis labels will be less width or more